# Do you need to update form DS-160 if you visit the US once again after making a visa appointment?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

A friend of mine is extending their US B1/B2 visa. He filled out form DS-160 which among other things asks about the last 5 visits to the US. Now he is going to travel to the US once again in the time between submitting the visa application and going for the visa appointment at the consulate.

Does he need to update form DS-160 to reflect this fact? Or maybe just mentioning it at the consulate is sufficient?